# Does joining a std::thread flush memory?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, synchronization, std

Consider this example:

```
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

std::string some_variable;

void writer_thread()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
    some_variable = "done";
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::thread w( &writer_thread );
        w.join();
    }

    std::cout << some_variable;
}
```

Is it necessary for me to add a synchronization mechanism to ensure that `some_variable` is correctly read from `main()` ?

Said differently: does joining or destructing a `std::thread` object imply that the memory associated to its local variable is flushed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`join` provides the necessary syncronisation. Anything you do after a successful `join` will be correctly synchronised with anything the thread did before ending.

From the standard (C++11 30.3.1.5 [thread.thread.member]/5), specifying the behaviour of `thread::join`:

> *Synchronization:* The completion of the thread represented by `*this` synchronizes with the corresponding successful `join()` return.