# Who is the creator of a std::future?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

[Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) says about `std::future` that

> The creator of the asynchronous operation can then use a variety of methods to query, wait for, or extract a value from the std::future.

Who is the creator of the asynchronous operation? Is it the thread that creates the `std::future` object, or any thread that has access to that object? In the end, my question is if non-creators can also use the `get` method on the `std::future`.

In particular, I would like to know if this piece of code is correct:

```
std::future<int> foo;
std::thread t([&foo](){ 
    foo = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ return 4; });
});
t.join();
int n = foo.get();  // can the main thread call foo.get()?
```

Comment: Can you explain what your concern is regarding the snippet your provided? Which part or line are you unsure about?

Comment: The same as the owner of any other object. In that snippet, the "stack frame" in which `foo` is declared

Comment: If it is called in main you are correct otherwise it is in the scope of declaration

Comment: You can do `foo.get()` as `foo` is in scope. But your `t.join()` makes sure that it is already finished.

Comment: My doubts are if other "non-creators" can also use the `std::future` object.

Comment: who is the owner of `int`? who is the owner of `std::string`? who is the owner of `std::ifstream`?

Comment: @David, yes but to be fair the documentation of std::string doesn't talk about "the owner" of the std::string.

Comment: I should have used the term "creator" instead of "owner" in the title of the question.

Comment: and where does it talk about the ownership of `std::future`?

Comment: I can definitively see how the wording could be confusing. Ownership has several other meanings, which are more complex than just scope resolution. For example, smart pointers exist to make the semantics ownership of objects explicit. And only the thread that owns a mutex lock is allowed to unlock it. I'm fairly certain that `std::future` is not one of those cases and that the documentation just refers to anything that has access to it, but I can't find a source to cite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who is the creator of the asynchronous operation? Is it the thread that creates the std::future object, or any thread that has access to that object?

There are essentially 3 things that can create such "asynchronous operation":

- `std::async`
- `std::promise`
- `std::packaged_task`

These "creators" create a so called *shared state*, in which the `std::future` obtained equally shares access to. The *shared state* is where the results of such operation is stored. both the provider (an `std::async`, `std::promise`, or `std::packaged_task` object) and the consumer (the `std::future` obtained) accesses the *shared state* in a thread safe manner, its an implementation detail you shouldn't be bothered about.

> In the end, my question is if non-creators can also use the get method on the `std::future`.

Of cause; An "asynchronous operation" typically takes place in a different thread of execution, and the purpose of `std::future` is to **safely** query and access the results of such "asynchronous operation" happening somewhere else, without you explicitly using any extra synchronization mechanism.

> In particular, I would like to know if this piece of code is correct:
>
> ```
> std::future<int> foo;
> std::thread t([&foo](){ 
>     foo = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ return 4; });
> });
> t.join();
> int n = foo.get();  // can the main thread call foo.get()?
> ```

While this "particular short snippet" doesn't seem to invoke a race condition; It's not in any way a good code. At any point in time, the `std::future` to a *shared state* obtained from an "asynchronous operation" should not be used by multiple thread at a time.

*In your case, the `get()` and the `assignment operator` isn't thread-safe. And sooner or later, this code will quickly grow to invoke a race-condition*

One more note, the use of a `std::thread` in your code isn't needed, in practice a decent implementation will create a new thread or use a thread pool when your *launch policy* is `std::launch::async`. Hence you should just do:

```
std::future<int> foo = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ return 4; });
int n = foo.get();
```

Comment: The `thread` of the snippet is for illustration purposes only. However, I don't understand why the snippet can create a race condition. Doesn't `t.join()` protect `get` from racing against `operator=`?

Comment: @ChronoTiger, there's no race condition at that snippet,  however, you are misusing of both `std::thread` and `std::future`. There's a very high chance that if you continue writing code that way,  you'll introduce a race condition sooner than you know. Please reread my answer carefully

Comment: Now I understand you meant that `get` and the `assignment operator` are not thread-safe operations in general, and not in my specific snippet. I know I could just wrote `int n = 4`, but that does not exemplify the question I wanted to ask with that MWE.
I appreciate your answer. Could you tell me if you agree with @David Haim's answer above, which says the snippet shows undefined behavior?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger, No, I do not agree with David's answer that the snippet invokes Undefined Behavior. Note that: `t.join()` synchronizes with the completion of the thread `t` - All writes done in the thread `t` is guaranteed to be complete and visible to the thread waiting for the `join()` (after the `join()` is returns without an exception). See a [**very similar question to yours**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684369/implicit-synchronization-when-creating-joining-threads). And see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109314/does-joining-a-stdthread-flush-memory) also...